# Azure CTP signup

Tags: azure

I am trying to signup to the Azure CTP but am finding the whole process real non user friendly. On this http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/ web page it gives me a link to go to get a token, but when I click it doesn't appear to do anything. It takes me to another page but doesn't tell me if a token has been sent or I have to do something else.

On the dashboard of Microsoft Connect it tells me my status in Azure is 'Participating'. What does this mean? I am not participating because I don't have a token. The whole process is very frustrating!

Is it possible to contact an actual person?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already submitted a request for a token.  I tried to sign up a week ago or so and I haven't received anything yet.  However, I did get my SQL Azure license and it seems to be working well.

Also, you are absolutely correct, their website is a mess and it's very hard to figure things out.  I hope they will be cleaning it up soon!

And I don't think they have any kind of support setup yet.

Comment: Were you able to work with the sample code and local fabric emulation without the "token"?